# Разрабатывая библиотеки, нужно ли динамически валидировать параметры в TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, валидация

Зная даже поверхностно, как работает TypeScript, несложно ответить: "Да. TypeScript лишь выполняет транспайлинг кода в JavaScript при этом не добавляя в него никакой функциональности, в том числе валидацию входных параметров". Например, приведённая ниже функция:

```typescript
function example(parameter: string): void {
  console.log(parameter.charAt(1));
}
```

будет конвертирована в:

```js
"use strict";
function example(parameter) {
  console.log(parameter.charAt(1));
}
```

Если пользователь JavaScript вызовет, скажем, `example(3)` то будет выброшено исключение `Uncaught TypeError: parameter.charAt is not a function`.

Хорошо, но если я итак это знаю, зачем я задаю этот вопрос? Затем что если всё действительно так плохо, то предостоит вложить очень много времени и сил в модификацию библиотек, но самое главное - увеличить их объём в **несколько раз**. И это не преувеличение. Например, в случае [@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions](https://github.com/TokugawaTakeshi/Yamato-Daiwa-ES-Extensions/blob/master/CoreLibrary/Package/README.md), на момент версии **1.6.x** функция [addElementsToArray](https://github.com/TokugawaTakeshi/Yamato-Daiwa-ES-Extensions/blob/master/CoreLibrary/Package/Documentation/Arrays/addElementsToArray/addElementsToArray.md) выглядела относительно просто и не имела никаких зависимостей:

```typescript
export default function addElementsToArray<ArrayElement>(
  namedParameters:
    {
      targetArray: Array<ArrayElement>;
      newElements: Array<ArrayElement>;
      mutably: boolean;
    } &
    (
      { toStart: true; } |
      { toEnd: true; } |
      { toPosition__numerationFrom0: number; } |
      { toPosition__numerationFrom1: number; }
    )
): Array<ArrayElement> {

  const workpiece: Array<ArrayElement> = namedParameters.mutably ?
      namedParameters.targetArray : [ ...namedParameters.targetArray ];

  if ("toStart" in namedParameters) {
    workpiece.unshift(...namedParameters.newElements);
    return workpiece;
  }


  if ("toEnd" in namedParameters) {
    workpiece.push(...namedParameters.newElements);
    return workpiece;
  }


  const positionOfFirstNewElement__numerationFrom0: number = "toPosition__numerationFrom0" in namedParameters ?
      namedParameters.toPosition__numerationFrom0 : namedParameters.toPosition__numerationFrom1 - 1;

  workpiece.splice(positionOfFirstNewElement__numerationFrom0, 0, ...namedParameters.newElements);

  return workpiece;
}
```

Однако, если добавить валидацию параметров (в данном случае с точки зрения грамматики ECMAScript парамер только один, типа "объект", но на концептуальном уровне каждое свойство объекта является параметром), то функция разрастётся до:

```typescript
import Logger from "../Logging/Logger";
import InvalidParameterValueError from "../Errors/InvalidParameterValue/InvalidParameterValueError";
import IncompatiblePropertiesInObjectTypeParameterError from
    "../Errors/IncompatiblePropertiesInObjectTypeParameter/IncompatiblePropertiesInObjectTypeParameterError";
import stringifyAndFormatArbitraryValue from "../Strings/stringifyAndFormatArbitraryValue";
import isArbitraryObject from "../TypeGuards/Objects/isArbitraryObject";
import isNotUndefined from "../TypeGuards/Nullables/isNotUndefined";
import isNonNegativeInteger from "../TypeGuards/Numbers/isNonNegativeInteger";
import isNaturalNumber from "../TypeGuards/Numbers/isNaturalNumber";


export default function addElementsToArray<ArrayElement>(
  namedParameters:
      Readonly<
        (
          {
            mutably: true;
            targetArray: Array<ArrayElement>;
          } |
          {
            mutably: false;
            targetArray: ReadonlyArray<ArrayElement>;
          }
        ) &
        {
          newElements: ReadonlyArray<ArrayElement>;
          toStart?: true;
          toEnd?: true;
          toPosition__numerationFrom0?: number;
          toPosition__numerationFrom1?: number;
        }
      >
): Array<ArrayElement> {

  if (!isArbitraryObject(namedParameters)) {
    Logger.throwErrorAndLog({
      errorInstance: new InvalidParameterValueError({
        parameterNumber: 1,
        parameterName: "namedParameters",
        messageSpecificPart: "The first and only parameter of 'addElementsToArray' must be of the object type."
      }),
      title: InvalidParameterValueError.localization.defaultTitle,
      occurrenceLocation: "addElementsToArray(namedParameters)"
    });
  }


  if (!Array.isArray(namedParameters.targetArray)) {
    Logger.throwErrorAndLog({
      errorInstance: new InvalidParameterValueError({
        parameterName: "namedParameters",
        parameterNumber: 1,
        messageSpecificPart: "The 'targetArray' is not the valid array and has value:\n" +
            `${ stringifyAndFormatArbitraryValue(namedParameters.targetArray) }`
      }),
      title: InvalidParameterValueError.localization.defaultTitle,
      occurrenceLocation: "addElementsToArray(namedParameters)"
    });
  }


  const alternativelyRequestOptions: Array<true | number> = [
    namedParameters.toStart,
    namedParameters.toEnd,
    namedParameters.toPosition__numerationFrom0,
    namedParameters.toPosition__numerationFrom1
  ].filter(isNotUndefined);

  if (alternativelyRequestOptions.length > 1) {

    Logger.logError({
      errorType: IncompatiblePropertiesInObjectTypeParameterError.NAME,
      title: IncompatiblePropertiesInObjectTypeParameterError.localization.defaultTitle,
      description: "Exactly one of 'toStart', 'toEnd', 'toPosition__numerationFrom0', 'toPosition__numerationFrom1' " +
          "must be specified while actually multiple of them has been. No elements will be added to target array.",
      occurrenceLocation: "addElementsToArray(namedParameters)"
    });

    return namedParameters.targetArray;

  }


  const workpiece: Array<ArrayElement> = namedParameters.mutably ?
      namedParameters.targetArray : [ ...namedParameters.targetArray ];

  if (namedParameters.toStart === true) {
    workpiece.unshift(...namedParameters.newElements);
    return workpiece;
  }


  if (namedParameters.toEnd === true) {
    workpiece.push(...namedParameters.newElements);
    return workpiece;
  }


  let positionOfFirstNewElement__numerationFrom0: number;

  if (isNonNegativeInteger(namedParameters.toPosition__numerationFrom0)) {
    positionOfFirstNewElement__numerationFrom0 = namedParameters.toPosition__numerationFrom0;
  } else if (isNaturalNumber(namedParameters.toPosition__numerationFrom1)) {
    positionOfFirstNewElement__numerationFrom0 = namedParameters.toPosition__numerationFrom1 - 1;
  } else {

    Logger.logError({
      errorType: InvalidParameterValueError.NAME,
      title: InvalidParameterValueError.localization.defaultTitle,
      description: alternativelyRequestOptions.length === 0 ?
          "None one of 'toStart', 'toEnd', 'toPosition__numerationFrom0', 'toPosition__numerationFrom1' has been specified." :
          (
            "The specified value of 'toStart', 'toEnd', 'toPosition__numerationFrom0' or 'toPosition__numerationFrom1' has " +
            "invalid type, value or numbers set."
          ) +
          "No elements will be added to target array.",
      occurrenceLocation: "addElementsToArray(namedParameters)"
    });

    return namedParameters.targetArray;

  }


  workpiece.splice(positionOfFirstNewElement__numerationFrom0, 0, ...namedParameters.newElements);

  return workpiece;

}
```

Итого, валидация заняла больше половины тела функции + появились зависимости. Иногда валидация можно занимать 90% тела функции и даже больше. Таким образом, размеры дистибутивов увеличатся в разы, что критично для фроент-енда, где каждый килобайт на счету.

А ведь приведённые выше валидации и ещё не самые дотошные, которые только могут быть! Мы можем также:

- Когда указано больше одного из взаимоисключающих параметров `toStart`, `toEnd`, `toPosition__numerationFrom0`, `toPosition__numerationFrom1`, определить, какие именно параметры были переданы и включить их имена в сообщение об ошибке (на данный момент просто будет сказано, что должен быть указан только один, но какой - пользователь библиотеки должен определить самостоятельно в процессе отладки).
- Разделить проверки на тип параметров, а также отсутствие всех взаимоисключающих вариантов (на данный момент сообщение об ошибке одно на эти два случая - в самом конце функции).
- Если параметры имеют неверный подтип (например, если `toStart` или `toEnd` имеют бессмысленное для данной функци значение `false` или же `toPosition__numerationFrom0` или `toPosition__numerationFrom1` принадлежан не тем множествам чисел), всё это логировать отедельно.

### Потенциальные ложные тревоги

Что же будет, если валидацию не выполнять? Корокий ответ - потенциальная потеря времени разработчиков / сотрудников поддержки на обработку большого количества баг тикетов.

От пользователей TypeScript, скорее всего, баг тикетов, связаннанных с отсутствием динамической валидации не поступит, если они исключат все ошибки TypeScript-а из своего кода. Но поскольку пользователей JavaScript если и не большинство, то значительное количество, то они могут открыть баг тикет с жалобами типа: "Эй! Твоя функция не рабоает!!! Она мне пишет: `Uncaught TypeError: parameter.charAt is not a function`. Какое вообще это имеет ко мне отношение и что прикажете делать?! Ты можешь делать так, чтобы функция мне чётко говорила, что не так?!". Даже если в итоге выяснится, что этот пользователь JavaScript просто передал не тот тип и в случае с TypeScript всё было бы нормально, то будет потрачено время на переписку, выясение обстоятельств и проверки кода. И таких случаев может быть много.

### Цель вопроса

Итак, мне нужно, чтобы разработчик с большим стажем сказал мне либо:

> Ты делаешь всё правильно, продолжай в том же духе. Поскольку TypeScript не выполняет валидацию параметров, то должен это сделать сам. Увеличение библиотек в разы не имеет значения даже для фронтенд-приложений, где каждый килобайт на счету, если это увеличение произошло из-за валидации.

или:

> Разрастание библиотек в несколько раз недопустимо даже по причине валидации параметров. Не трать время на эти валидации.

Comment: Я бы решил вопрос через документацию, где сказал бы что, функция принимает число, а если пользователь передает туда строку - он сам дурак. Тем более, если валидировать все кейсы - 100%, что какой-то кейс будет пропущен и так же придет пользователь. Может быть еще приложить к библиотеке файлик *.d.ts, чтобы пользователь на js, мог его тоже как-то посмотреть и на основе версии для ts-а понять что нужно передавать в функцию. Может быть jsDoc в помощь, описать в комментариях типы функций

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73410742/should-i-manually-validate-parameters-in-typescirpt-if-create-the-library

Comment: Идеальным решением было бы отбрасывать эти проверки при сборке в продакшен,, но придётся повозиться с конфигурацией сборщика, если он вообще такое позволяет.

Comment: Поддерживаю @SergeyGlazirin, а сам вопрос поставлен холиварно, будто есть сомнения в пользе статической типизации или недопонимание. Хорошо, можно откатиться назад как будто TS никогда не существовало, тогда все действительно станет плачевно. Жаль, что TS не отдельный язык, а надстройка над JS, но он позволяет на этапе разработки избежать ошибок и берет на себя даже самые глубокие проверки если не писать `any`, причем не увеличивая размер итогового кода. Думаю разработка библиотеки на TS предполагает что пользоваться ей будут так же проекты с TS либо использующие  *.d.ts файлы. Истина посреди.

Comment: Ну и никто не мешает писать понятные сообщения об ошибке, тут все зависит исключительно от разработчика, если код слишком запутан чтобы детектировать возможное неправильное его использование или плохо документирован, то стоит ли пенять на TS — чья сущность лишь помочь не запутаться в разрабатываемом коде, в том числе подсказками, но никак не сделать конфетку, за разработчика

Comment: решение зависит от целей с которой ты создаёшь библиотеку)

Comment: Вопрос дискуссионный, и на него не может быть дан однозначный ответ. Оба подхода имеют право на жизнь, и оба встречаются. Важно, чтобы это было чётко закреплено в документации. Конечное решение принимает архитектор.